# Is there a such thing as an ARINC label for the yaw angle?

Tags: avionics, datasets, yaw, arinc-429

Is there a way to check the yaw angle on the ARINC bus? If so, what is the associated ARINC-429 label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-authoritative list of some labels:

- [ARINC 429 Labels](https://sites.google.com/site/thel1011projectwiki/simulator-software/arinc-429-labels)

But labels are not all defined in ARINC standard, a specific LRU can define custom values. So you need to get label list from LRU documentation. For instance, labels used by Laseref VI IRS to output values to the bus are:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Honeywell](https://www51.honeywell.com/aero/common/documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/BA_brochures-documents/Laseref_VI_FINAL.pdf)</sup>

Your question is ambiguous about what you are looking for: Yaw is the rotation around an axis normal to the plan defined by longitudinal and pitch axes. The origin can be multiple:

[image]

It can be seen absolute, for instance referenced to the north, and it would be the heading. It can defined relatively to a given direction, e.g. the wind, and it would be computed from other values. More likely it can be a rate.

Here are some related labels:

- Yaw rate = 330
- Heading: True = 314, Mag = 320
- Track angle: True = 313, Mag = 317
- Wind direction: True = 316

(octal values)

Could you provide details about your needs?

Comment: The difference between heading and track is the wind drift angle, not the yaw.

Comment: I don't know the technical definition, but probably something like the difference between the heading and the relative wind.  If an aircraft has access to the yaw angle, it is typically from an accelerometer and not from other inputs.

Comment: The heading is the yaw angle.

Comment: Actually, it depends on what he is looking for.  Since an aircraft has a yaw axis, that could translate to the heading as DeltaLima points out. An aircraft can also perform the action knows at yawing, which is actually a rate of change in the heading, but as pilot's we typically refer to a yaw as the uncoordinated maneuver that can be obtained by simply pushing the rudder. In short, it's somewhat ambiguous...

Comment: I apologize for the lack of detail, thank you for this. I do realize the LRU manufacturer is at liberty to define what the labels actually mean, it's just that sometimes they don't tell you.

Comment: Does this post fully answer your question?